# Internet Explorer 8 Adding a second colgroup

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

In internet explorer 8, a second blank colgroup keeps being added to my DOM, that is not present in my code that keeps throwing off the width of my table. Has anyone seen this before?

```
<COLGROUP>
<COL>
<COL>
<COL>
<COL>
<COL>
<COL>
</COLGROUP>
<COLGROUP>
<COL style="WIDTH: 15%">
<COL style="WIDTH: 35%">
<COL style="WIDTH: 10%">
<COL style="WIDTH: 10%">
<COL style="WIDTH: 10%">
<COL style="WIDTH: 20%">
</COLGROUP>
```

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally, I've had this happen in IE when I've forgotten to close an element (for example, opening but not closing a paragraph will sometimes cause IE8 to insert another paragraph). To start, close your styles with a semi-colon or simply switch to the shorthand `<col width="35%">`, etc. I can't say for certain this will solve your problem, but it's a good place to start.